# PHP と ヘッドレスChrome の組み合わせで、Selenium を使用せずにスクリーンキャプチャを遅延取得したい

Tags: php, chromedriver

[PHPプログラムでChromeDriverを使って、ヘッドレスのChromeをリモート操作](http://www.ajisaba.net/develop/selenium/client_php_webdriver_chrome.html) でスクリーンキャプチャを取得できたのですが、一部のコンテンツ(遅れて表示される部分)が期待した通り取得されません。
そこで、対象ページが表示されてから5秒経過した時点のスクリーンキャプチャを取得したいのですが、どうすれば良いですか？

Comment: これらの記事 [Make Chrome Headless to Wait for Ajax Before Printing to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49614437/9014308), [ヘッドレスChromeでWebサイトのスクリーンショットを一括生成する](https://www.webopixel.net/javascript/1468.html) で、`--virtual-time-budget`というので指定出来るとかいてあります。あるいは最初に記事のコメントやこの記事 [How to take a screenshot of a page N seconds after page is loaded with Chrome Headless?](https://superuser.com/q/1209741) のように`puppeteer`を使うとか。

Comment: PHPで--virtual-time-budget指定したら「WebDriverException: The driver server has died.」エラーとなりました。コマンドで--virtual-time-budget指定したら、エラーにはならなかったのですがページ内の遅延表示部分が取得できませんでした。puppeteerを検討してみます